# booktabs with multicol: horizontal rules too short

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I need to typeset a two-column document (conference paper) & use the `multicol` package. I wish to insert a table & usually use the `booktabs` package as it gives nice spacing. However, in this case, the horizontal rules are truncated. Would anybody know what the problem is?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm,pdftex,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}
   \begin{tabular}{@{}ll rrrrr rrrrr@{}}
   \toprule
   \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Penalty} &\multicolumn{5}{c}{100 xx} &      \multicolumn{5}{c}{1000 xxx} \\
   \cmidrule(rl){3-7}\cmidrule(rl){8-12}
    & $s$ & $\nu$& G & E & P & D & G& E & P & D \\
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{12}{c}{\it abcd } \\
   P40 &2&  10&  -62&  -23&   -6& -13.15&     22&   -5&    0&  -0.84\\
   P41   &   1&   --&   55&   28&    1&  -4.94&  34&    7&    0&  -1.23\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
  \end{multicols}
  \end{document}
```

and here is what I get - the lines seem to be truncated before the right edge of column 1:
[image: screenshot of offending table]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, your `tabular` environment has 11 rather than 12 columns. Getting rid of the `\multicolumn` wrapper around the header item "Penalty" and adjusting the column counts on some of the other items fixes this issue.

Separately, in view of the fact that most of the columns would appear to contain numerical data, some with negative values, you may want to use a more suitable column type than `r` to align the numbers. For instance, you could use the `D` column type provided by the `dcolumn` package, as is done in the example below. (An alternative to the `dcolumn` package would be the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}  % shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}[t]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{d{2.0}} *{2}{d{3.0}} d{2.0}
        d{3.2} *{3}{d{2.0}} d{2.2} @{}}
   \toprule
   Penalty 
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{100 xx} 
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{1000 xxx} \\
   \cmidrule(rl){2-6}\cmidrule(l){7-11}
    & s & \nu & \mc{G} & \mc{E} & \mc{P} & 
     \mc{D} & \mc{G}& \mc{E} & \mc{P} & \mc{D} \\
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{11}{c}{\itshape abcd } \\
   P40 &2& 10& -62&  -23&   -6& -13.15& 22& -5& 0&  -0.84\\
   P41   &   1&   -&   55& 28&  1& -4.94& 34& 7& 0&  -1.23\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
  \end{multicols}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: thank you VERY much - can't believe I didn't spot this; normally I'd expect to get an error about too few columns on compilation in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

[image]

An & is missing in the first column

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}
   \begin{tabular}{@{}ll rrrrr rrrrr@{}}
   \toprule
   \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Penalty} &\multicolumn{5}{c}{100 xx} &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{1000 xxx} \\
   \cmidrule(rl){3-7}\cmidrule(rl){8-12}
    & & $s$ & $\nu$& G & E & P & D & G& E & P & D \\
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{12}{c}{\it abcd } \\
   & P40 &2&  10&  -62&  -23&   -6& -13.15&     22&   -5&    0&  -0.84\\
   & P41   &   1&   --&   55&   28&    1&  -4.94&  34&    7&    0&  -1.23\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
  \end{multicols}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the number of columns from 12 to 11, solves the problem. Here is the modified file:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm,pdftex,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}
   \begin{tabular}{@{}ll rrrrr rrrrr@{}}
   \toprule
   \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Penalty} &\multicolumn{5}{c}{100 xx} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1000 xxx} \\
   \cmidrule(rl){3-7}\cmidrule(rl){8-11}
    & $s$ & $\nu$& G & E & P & D & G& E & P & D \\
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{11}{c}{\it abcd } \\
   P40 &2&  10&  -62&  -23&   -6& -13.15&     22&   -5&    0&  -0.84\\
   P41   &   1&   --&   55&   28&    1&  -4.94&  34&    7&    0&  -1.23\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]